# How to detect Aruco marker and analyze my robot position

Tags: java, opencv, augmented-reality, robotics, aruco

I have compete a KiboRobot Programming challenge. I need to move my robot to the point and shoot the laser to the target (Green Circle). But my problem is when I arrive infront of the point I don't know how to move my robot to float infront of the Point. So I want to know how to detect a Aruco marker and what should I do next.

```
public class YourService extends KiboRpcService {
    @Override
    protected void runPlan1(){
        api.startMission();

        moveTo(11.114, -7.9756, 5.3393, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5);

        Mat image = api.getMatNavCam();
        api.saveMatImage(image, "image.png");

        laser(true);



}
public void moveTo(double x, double y, double z, double qx, double qy, double qz, double w) {
        Point point = new Point(x, y, z);
        Quaternion quaternion = new Quaternion((float)qx, (float)qy, (float)qz, (float)w);
        Result result = api.moveTo(point, quaternion, false);

        final int loop_MAX = 5;
        int loop_count = 0;
        while (!result.hasSucceeded() && loop_count <= loop_MAX) {
            result = api.moveTo(point, quaternion, true);
            loop_count++;
        }
    }
    public void laser(boolean shoot) {
        if (shoot) {
            api.laserControl(true);
        }
}
```

ํYou can search more details about Kibo-rpc. Please help me. I stuck in this problem for 4 days ( I search on youtube, google and also ChatGPT but still confuse )
[This image is from cam on robot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHnGJ.png)
[This from rulebook of competetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH8SF.png)

How to detect Aruco marker. and move my robot to the center of point.

Comment: Do these articels help? [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) [java example code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74013320/18667225)